# Duplicate rows in left join

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have 2 tables. There are about 100000 of null in one column, other values are integer, total values are about 200000. Another table has only the integer value. When I use the left join on this column, it gave me a lot of duplicates rows. Is it ok to use left join here?

```
Table 1: 
Column 1
2
3
5
null 
null

Table 2: 
Column 1
1
2
3
so on
```

[image]

Comment: what does your query look like?

Comment: What is your current query and also what is your expected output?

Comment: select id, Name from Table1 
left join Table2 
on Table1.id=Table2.id

Comment: why are you using `left join`?

Comment: @ zealous , there are some other columns in table2 that I need

Comment: what is your expected output of the left join. The img you have shows up nulls of table1 are these the duplicates you want to get riid of?

Comment: The type of query depends on the results that you want.  You have not explained that.

Answer (score 1):

Your example is really odd. Why would anyone have null values in an ID field? But anyway.
If you need fields from table 2 in the resultset as you say above then you must use an INNER JOIN not a LEFT JOIN

Something like:

```
    SELECT DISTINCT a.id, a.name, b.someOtherField
      FROM Table1 a
INNER JOIN Table2 b ON a.id = b.id
```

Please note: Since only the ID field of table 1 has null values there will be no records selected from table 1 with id IS NULL because they have no equivalent in table 2. Adding the DISTINCT keyword helps in case this query would still produce duplicates.